# XMPP Roster presence

Tags: xmpp, user-presence, rostering

I've a problem with roster mechanism and I'm using JSJaC javascript library.

My case:

The user A has a simple roster that contains another user B with subscription "both". The user B has the same configuration.

When the user A is logged to openfire, I call my "getRoster()" function that returns the user's list of friends (in my case, only the user B), but how I can check if user B is currently available to chat?

I see that there are some presence mechanisms, but I don't understand how I can use these.

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you send your own presence to the server then server starts sending all the presences of your subscribed contacts to you. You have to consider all contacts as offline by default.

I am not familiar with JSJaC, but there is probably a callback where the presence comes in.

Answer (score 0):

You should register a `presence` handler. Assuming you have roster as array of user data you can do it like this:

```
xmpp.registerHandler 'presence', (response) ->
  user = _.find @roster, jid: (response.getFrom().split '/').shift()
  if user
    if response.getType() is 'unavailable'
      user.online = no
    else
      user.online = yes
```